# UIButton : managing dynamic creation and touch events

Tags: iphone, dynamic, uibutton, creation

I'm currently dynamically creating UIButton objects in my view.

I have an NSMutableArray containing information about them (id - label).

I then create my view objects by doing a for iteration on my MutableArray.

I'm trying to use this code on my buttons to catch touche events :

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectedButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

My selectedButton method is called with success, but I don't have any idea on knowing with button were touched.

I tried to do this :

```
-(void)selectedButton:(id)sender {...}
```

But don't know what to do with the sender object.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `mybutton.tag` to something, and then check for that tag in `selectedButton:sender`.

Answer (score 3):

At the top of your .m file, put something like this:

```
enum {
    kButtonOne,
    kButtonTwo  
};
```

When you're creating your buttons, do this

```
myButton.tag = kButtonOne;
```

Then in your selected button method, do this:

```
-(void)selectedButton:(id)sender {
  switch (sender.tag) {
    case kButtonOne:
      // do something here
      break;
    case kButtonTwo:
      // do something else here
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 40.0, 30.0);

button.tag=1;

[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[button setTitle:@"raaz" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:button];

}

-(IBAction)aMethod:(id)sender{

UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;

NSLog(@"I have currently Pressed button=%d",btn.tag);


}
```